# Como contar positivos y negativos de una matriz. Luego sumar positivos y negativos

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Hice esto, pero no se como plantear la siguiente funcion porque son de n columnas y en los casos que he visto siempre es espacifico el numero de columnas

Y yo quiero sumar los positivos y los negativos de dicha matriz.
Tambien podria contar cuantos positivos y cuantos negativos.

En el retorno tambien tengo problema. Alguna idea, por favor.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
 
using namespace std;
 
 
 int matriz(int[],int m, int n);
 int posi_nega(int [][100], int m, int n);
 int par_impar(int[],int m, int n);
 
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int m,n;
    cout << "Numero de filas: "; cin >> m;
    cout << "Numero de columnas: "; cin >> n;
    int matriz[m][n];
    cout << "\n La matriz A es:"<<endl<<endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
           matriz[m][n] = rand() % (m*n-(-m*n)+1)+(-m*n); 
           cout << matriz[m][n] << "    ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
  
    return 0;
}
```

[image: por ejemplo me hace esta matriz.]
Aqui pueden ver de una matriz que genero. Pero si quiero la siguiente funcion. tendria que ser un n especifico. Yo meti que el rango sea de (-m*n, m*n) en este caso (-25,25).

Comment: No veo que hayas intentado nada, pero es muy fácil. Solo tiene que recorrerla con ciclos anidados y guardar los datos que quieres en variables.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es ir validando cada vez que se obtenga el dato... osea... con forme se va llenando la matriz... asi ya no tienes que leer toda la matriz de nuevo... te ahorras mas tiempo y recursos.

Comment: No se debe definir arreglos dinámicos con variables `int matriz[m][n];` C++ necesita una contante en tiempo de compilación para poder definir la matriz. Aún así, es probable que SI te esté funcionando (de hecho a mi también); eso es porque algunos compiladores, en mi caso GCC, g++, permiten hacerlo. Sin embargo, porque lo permita no es correcto ya que no es estándar de C++. Tienes dos opciones, definir un array grande `[100][100]` o usar punteros con `new` y `delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulto perfecto, muchas gracias por sus aportes!!!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//  Marco Molina  @Copyright 2020
//  
//  2020
 
int positivos[100000];
int negativos[100000];
int pares[100000];
int impares[100000];


void muestra(int num[], int tam);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int m,n, sumap=0, suman=0, sumapar=0,sumai=0, contp=0, contn=0, contpar=0, conti=0 ;
    
    int numpositivos=0;
    int numnegativos=0;
    int numpares=0;
    int numimpares=0;
     
    
    cout << "Numero de filas: "; cin >> m;
    cout << "Numero de columnas: "; cin >> n;
    int matriz[m][n];
    cout << "\n La matriz A es:"<<endl<<endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
           matriz[i][j] = rand() % (m*n-(-m*n)+1)+(-m*n); 
           cout << setw (7)<< matriz[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
    
    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
            if (matriz [i][j]<0){
                suman+=matriz[i][j];
                contn=contn+1;
                negativos[numnegativos] = matriz[i][j];
               numnegativos++;
                
            }   
            else{
                sumap+=matriz[i][j];
                contp=contp+1;
                positivos[numpositivos] = matriz[i][j];
               numpositivos++;
                
            }
        }       
    }
    
    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
            if (matriz [i][j]%2==0){
                sumapar+=matriz[i][j];
                contpar=contpar+1;
                pares[numpares] = matriz[i][j];
                numpares++;
            }   
            else{
                sumai=matriz[i][j];
                conti=conti+1;
                impares[numimpares] = matriz[i][j];
                numimpares++;
            }
        }       
    }
    
    cout<< "---------------POSITIVOS---------------"<<endl;
    cout<< " El valor de los numeros positivos es: " << sumap <<endl;
    cout<< " El numero de positivos es: " << contp <<endl;
    cout<< " Los cuales son:" ;
    muestra(positivos, numpositivos); cout << endl;
     cout<< "---------------NEGATIVOS---------------"<<endl;
    cout<< " El valor de los numeros negativos es: " << suman <<endl;
    cout<< " El numero de negativos es: " << contn <<endl;
    cout<< " Los cuales son:" ;
    muestra(negativos, numnegativos); cout << endl;
     cout<< "-----------------PARES-----------------"<<endl;
    cout<< " El valor de los numeros par es: " << sumapar <<endl;
    cout<< " El numero de pares es: " << contpar <<endl;
    cout<< " Los cuales son:" ;
    muestra(pares, numpares);cout << endl;
     cout<< "----------------IMPARES----------------"<<endl;
    cout<< " El valor de los numeros impar es: " << sumai <<endl;
    cout<< " El numero de impares es: " << conti <<endl;
    cout<< " Los cuales son:" ;
    muestra(impares, numimpares); cout << endl; cout << endl;
    cout<< " La resta de numeros pares e impares:"<< sumapar-sumai <<endl;
    cout<< " La suma de numeros positivo y negativos:"<< sumap+suman <<endl;

    return 0;
}


void muestra(int num[], int tam)
{
   cout<<"\n[ ";
   for(int i=0; i< tam; i++)
      cout<< num[i] << " ";
   
    cout<<"]" <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay que aprovechar el propio bucle que usas para generar la matriz y ahí ya vamos haciendo los cálculos:

```
// Arrays que contendrán los números
// que responden al filtro que queremos
int arrPositives[25];
int arrNegatives[25];
// Esta función se encargará de mostrar los arrays 
void ShowArray(int num[], int size);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int m,n;
    cout << "Numero de filas: "; cin >> m;
    cout << "Numero de columnas: "; cin >> n;
    int matriz[m][n];
    cout << "\n La matriz A es:"<<endl<<endl;
    
    // Estas variables para nuestros cálculos
    int numPositives=0, sumPositives = 0;
    int numNegatives=0, sumNegatives = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
           // Generamos y mostramos la matriz
           matriz[m][n] = rand() % (m*n-(-m*n)+1)+(-m*n);
           cout << matriz[m][n] << "\t";
           // Aprovechamos que estamos generando los números de
           // la matriz para preguntar si son positivos o negativos
           // y según sean procedemos al recuento y suma.
           if (matriz[m][n] >= 0)
           {
               arrPositives[numPositives] = matriz[m][n];
               numPositives++;
               sumPositives+=matriz[m][n];
           }
           else
           {
               arrNegatives[numNegatives] = matriz[m][n];
               numNegatives++;
               sumNegatives+=matriz[m][n];
           }

           // Aquí más condicionales para otros cálculos
           // si se desea, para los pares, impares, primos ...

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    // Mostramos cantidades y sumatorios de los Positivos y Negativos
    cout<<"\n Existen (" << numPositives << ") números positivos que suman " << sumPositives;
    ShowArray(arrPositives, numPositives);

    cout<<"\n Existen (" << numNegatives << ") números negativos que suman " << sumNegatives;
    ShowArray(arrNegatives, numNegatives);

    return 0;
}
```

Nos creamos esta pequeña función para mostrar el array de números seleccionados:

```
void ShowArray(int num[], int size)
{
   cout<<"\n[ ";
   for(int i=0; i< size; i++)
      cout<< num[i] << " ";
   
    cout<<"]" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Antonio S.F.

Comment: Ya lo habia conseguido, pero igual muchas gracias. Mi unica duda seria como hago el arreglo para que me muestre especificamente cual es cual .puedes ver arriba.

Comment: No entiendo, pero en tu código recorres la matriz para cada cálculo y no es necesario. Lo puedes hacer todo en el bucle que genera la propia matriz. Añade los condicionales ahí.

Comment: He editado la respuesta y ya marca las pautas de lo que pretendes conseguir. Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Eso era exactamente lo que pretendia. Muchas gracias, de verdad muy amable.

Answer (score 0):

@gcoronel99 Lo hice, ahora quiero que me diga especificamente cuales son los positivos, negativos, par e impares.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//  Marco Molina  @Copyright 2020
// PROGRAMACION I 
// II PAC 2020
 

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int m,n, sumap=0, suman=0, sumapar=0,sumai=0, contp=0, contn=0, contpar=0, conti=0 ;
    cout << "Numero de filas: "; cin >> m;
    cout << "Numero de columnas: "; cin >> n;
    int matriz[m][n];
    cout << "\n La matriz A es:"<<endl<<endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
           matriz[i][j] = rand() % (m*n-(-m*n)+1)+(-m*n); 
           cout << setw (7)<< matriz[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
    
    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
            if (matriz [i][j]<0){
                suman+=matriz[i][j];
                contn=contn+1;
            }   
            else{
                sumap+=matriz[i][j];
                contp=contp+1;
            }
        }       
    }
    
    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
            if (matriz [i][j]%2==0){
                sumapar+=matriz[i][j];
                contpar=contpar+1;
            }   
            else{
                sumai=matriz[i][j];
                conti=conti+1;
            }
        }       
    }
    
    cout<< "el valor de los numeros positivos es: " << sumap <<endl;
    cout<< "el numero de positivos es: " << contp <<endl;
    cout<< "el valor de los numeros negativos es: " << suman <<endl;
    cout<< "el numero de negativos es: " << contn <<endl;
    cout<< "el valor de los numeros par es: " << sumapar <<endl;
    cout<< "el numero de pares es: " << contpar <<endl;
    cout<< "el valor de los numeros impar es: " << sumai <<endl;
    cout<< "el numero de impares es: " << conti <<endl<<endl;
    cout<< "La resta de numeros pares e impares:"<< sumapar-sumai <<endl;
    cout<< "La suma de numeros positivo y negativos:"<< sumap+suman <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guarda los negativos en un Array y los positivos en otro Array... y listo. :)